# Какую сущность выбрать в schema.org для обучающего сайта

Tags: schema.org

Прошу помочь. Для добавления микроразметки на сайте надо добавлять сущности из `https://schema.org`Я нашел восемь:

1. Action
2. Creative work
3. Event
4. Intangible (нематериальное)
5. Organization
6. Person
7. Place
8. Product
   В моем сайте `https://www.trenajor.me` 4 типа страниц:
9. Заглавная, где я рассказываю, про свою разработку онлайн тренажер. (что нужно использовать product, creative work или intangible?)
10. Контакты, где говорю где мой офис и мои контакты (что использовать Organization, Person, Place?)
11. Страница Поле БОЯ , там происходит процесс работы тренажера (Action, Creative work, Intangible, Product?)
12. Страницы с контентом типа как учить английский, реклама курса по английскому (Creative work, Intangible, Product?)